# Not able to click/Mouse over an element using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

1.go to  this URL :->http://wallethub.com/profile/test_insurance_company/

2.On the right part of the page, hover over the stars and click on the fifth star
code should actually (1) do the hover and (2) make sure the stars inside get lit up when you hover over them, then (3) click on the fifth star.

The following doesn't work

```
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Wallethub2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProfilesIni prof = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile fp = prof.getProfile("sel");

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(fp);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://wallethub.com/profile/test_insurance_company/");

//      Xpaths of 5 stars
       String star1="//div[@class='wh-rating-choices-holder']/a[contains(@href, '#')][1]";
       String star2="//div[@class='wh-rating-choices-holder']/a[contains(@href, '#')][2]";
       String star3="//div[@class='wh-rating-choices-holder']/a[contains(@href, '#')][3]";
       String star4="//div[@class='wh-rating-choices-holder']/a[contains(@href, '#')][4]";
       String star5="//div[@class='wh-rating-choices-holder']/a[contains(@href, '#')][5]";

        WebElement srating1=driver.findElement(By.xpath(star1));            
        WebElement srating2=driver.findElement(By.xpath(star2));            
        WebElement srating3=driver.findElement(By.xpath(star3));            
        WebElement srating4=driver.findElement(By.xpath(star4));            
        WebElement srating5=driver.findElement(By.xpath(star5));    


        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  
                builder.moveToElement(srating1).build().perform();
        builder.moveToElement(srating1).build().perform();
        builder.moveToElement(srating2).build().perform();
        srating3.click();








    }

}
```

Comment: Is the Code doing any of the above tasks? (hover)

Comment: Is it working? Is it throwing any error? Can you post the logs?

Comment: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to click on the fifth star should it be `srating5.click()`

Or if there is an issue with your code try using:

```
Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) driver.findElement(srating1);

Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();

mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
```

To do the hover for the first star then repeat.

The for the last item you should be able to do what you are doing or try

```
Locatable clickItem = (Locatable)driver.findElement(srating3).getLocation();
clickItem.getCordinates(clickItem).click();
```

Comment: Thanks, 'mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());' worked for me to do 'on mouse up' element.